# Media queries and 2 column layout: arbitrary positioning

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design

We've just started to redesign our site following the responsive web design + mobile first philosophy and guidelines.

In a particular page, we are facing the following situation: in the "mobile view" of the page we want to have the elements arranged as the left part of the image shows.

[image: The two desired layouts]

That's why in the HTML these elements are declared as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="A">A</div>
    <div id="B">B</div>
    <div id="C">C</div>
    <div id="D">D</div>
    <div id="E">E</div>
</div>
```

Up to this point, all of it is straightforward. The problem is that, using media queries, for higher screen resolutions we want to rearrange the items as shown in the right part of the image.

The general question, which solves our particular problem with this page, is: is it possible to float arbitrary elements to each of the two columns without having to change the HTML markup between the two versions? A pure CSS solution would be much desired.

*Note:* the height of the elements is unknown, and the width is percentual.

**EDIT:** For clarification, and regarding our particular case, we need the item E to be attached under item B, and not vertically aligned to D. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5d7zU/5/) shows what we don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could float `A`, `C` and `D` to the right. However you might need to apply `overflow:auto` to `B` and `E`. Also note, that if `B` is higher than `A`, `C` is getting pushed down to align accordingly.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/4YvX9/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That was what we were looking for. Why do you say we might need to apply `overflow: auto` to B? Is it to prevent B from growing more than A because of its contents?

Comment: @pau.moreno As you are working with fixed widths, ignore that;) (I was thinking of fluid layout...my fault)

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="A">A</div>
    <div id="B" class = "left">B</div>
    <div id="C">C</div>
    <div id="D">D</div>
    <div id="E" class = "left">E</div>
</div>
<style>
.left { float:left; }
</style>
```

You can just set float:left in the media query you want and ignore it in the other one.

#### Edit:

In response to OP's feedback that B and D were not sitting directly on top of each other, revising the code to float: right instead fixes this. ie

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="A" class = "right">A</div>
    <div id="B" >B</div>
    <div id="C" class = "right">C</div>
    <div id="D" class = "right">D</div>
    <div id="E" >E</div>
</div>
<style>
.right { float:right; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result of this approach is that E is not attached to B (which is what we want), but in line with D: http://jsfiddle.net/5d7zU/5/

Comment: Ah I see. A minor modification to use float: right instead of left would fix it - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrKx5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

For the normal layout, you should do it like this.
Both `div`s should be left floated.

```
<div id="container1">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="B">B</div>
        <div id="E">E</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="A">A</div>
        <div id="C">C</div>
        <div id="D">D</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the mobile version uses another arrangement.
So one solution is to make onther version for the mobile page and hide `#container1` (and vice versa for the other site).

```
<div id="container2">
    <div id="A">A</div>
    <div id="B">B</div>
    <div id="C">C</div>
    <div id="D">D</div>
    <div id="E">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that would alter the markup, wich is against the will of the OP.